# curl always connects to a specific ip:port pair

Tags: linux, curl

I'm running into this scenario on one of our linux boxes.

```
$ curl 10.200.20.66:8087/ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 219.135.102.36 port 8118: Connection timed out

$ curl 114.114.114.114:80/x
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 219.135.102.36 port 8118: Connection timed out
```

As you can see, curl has always been trying to connect 219.135.102.36:8118.

I've tried using `nc` and `telnet` and both of them give correct results.

Finally I've turned to `strace curl 10.200.20.66:8087/ping` and here's [output](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dunjut/stickers/master/strace_curl).

Can anybody help explain why this happened?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks @DanielStenberg. I already checked environment variables, no HTTP_PROXY or similar is set.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Have you read the strace output? I can not quite understand that, don't know if it helps

Comment: unfortunately that mostly confirms what you've described, it doesn't show how/where the new address appears (from) or why it gets used instead. A curlrc file would've been another guess but the strace shows it wasn't used either...

Comment: @DanielStenberg It should be installed from apt source. (version 7.47.0) The md5 checksum is correct compared with another binary installed on another machine which works fine.

Comment: @DanielStenberg  I just re-checked the environment variables, the http_proxy does exist (in lower case), it's my fault to mislead you into a strange behavior. I'm going to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure what is happening, turn on verbosity with `-v` switch:

```
$ http_proxy=1.2.3.4:8080 curl -v http://google.com
* About to connect() to proxy 1.2.3.4 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

In your case, I'd guess that Curl tries to use proxy. If that is the case, you should check the following:

- `http_proxy` environment variable:

Check:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

- Curl configuration file `~/.curlrc` (unlikely, it doesn't show in `strace`)
- Proxy can be proxided on command line (`-x` or `--proxy`), so check if `curl` isn't aliased in your shell

Answer (score -2):

Curl should be used with website, http,https,ftp.

example curl "http://www.google.com"

it provides the output in html format

Kindly check and try in correct format